# SQL Server 2008 R2: Dynamic query for pivot table with where and having clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

**Note**: This post is slightly change with previous post.

I have the following table with the details as shown below in the example.

**Example**:

**Table:** test

```
create table test
(
 cola varchar(10),
 colb varchar(10),
 colc varchar(10)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
insert into test values('101','1234','A1');
insert into test values('101','4321','A2');
insert into test values('201','5678','A3');
insert into test values('301','8765','A4');
insert into test values('401','9877','A1');
 insert into test values('101','9997','A6');
 insert into test values('201','2277','A1');
 insert into test values('201','1577','A5');
```

**Note**: Now I want to show only that records in which `cola` belongs to `colc`'s values. If the user pass the `colc` values as a parameter to stored procedure then it has to match the exact value of `colc` belongs to which `cola` value.

**Expected Result**:

If the user pass `A1,A2,A6` then the result should be:

```
cola   A1   A2   A6
--------------------
101    1      1     1
```

**Note**: In the above result the record `101` appears because it belongs to `A1,A2,A6` not other values. `201` not appear because that belongs to `A1,A3` and `A5` also.

If the user pass `A1` then the result should be:

```
cola   A1 
--------
401    1
```

**Note**: In the above result the record `401` appears because it belongs to `A1`.

## My Attempt:

**Pivot Query**:

```
DECLARE @Stuff varchar(max) = 'A1'
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT cola,' +@Stuff+ '
            from
            (
                select cola,colc
                from test 
                where colc in(''A1'')
                group by cola,colc
                having count(distinct colc) = 1

            )p
            PIVOT
            (
                COUNT(colc)
                FOR colc IN ('+@Stuff+')
            )AS pvt'

PRINT(@Sql)
EXEC(@Sql)
```

**Getting Result**:

```
cola    A1  
----------
101     1
401     1
```

You can go here for practicle:

## SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b1fd/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this :

```
DECLARE @Stuff varchar(max) = 'A1'
        DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)
    DECLARE @totalparam int = 1
        SET @Sql = 'SELECT cola,' +@Stuff+ '
                    from
                    (
                        select cola,colc
                        from test a
                        where colc in(''A1'')
                        group by cola,colc
                        having (select count(colc) from test b where b.cola = a.cola )  = @totalparam

                    )p
                PIVOT
                (
                    COUNT(colc)
                    FOR colc IN ('+@Stuff+')
                )AS pvt'

    PRINT(@Sql)
    EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the expected result. Please recheck it.

Comment: I'm sorry.. i mean this code : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b1fd/72
you could modify it to set totalparam as parameter.

Comment: Nope! Totally wrong. If you give input as `A1,A2,A6` then it has to return record `101` with the details.

Comment: yes, it does. have you checked the result? it's on the bottom. please check the result. it is 101 with the detail.
in addition, you could modify your list and total param :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40185/3

Comment: I refine the query in case if the input as 'A1,A3' :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40185/7

Comment: This query is taking too much time to execute for huge records: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b2e1/1 , Will you please suggest me some modification?

Comment: Okay let me try this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @Stuff VARCHAR(max) = 'A1,A2'--'A1'
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(max),
        @cnt INT

SELECT @cnt = Count(1)
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@Stuff, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT cola,' + @Stuff+ ' from
                (SELECT a.cola, a.colc
                 FROM   test a
                 JOIN (SELECT cola
                 FROM   test
                 GROUP  BY cola
                 HAVING Count(DISTINCT colc) = '
           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @cnt)+ ') B
                 ON a.cola = b.cola
                 where colc in (select rtrim(ltrim(Split.a.value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(100)'')))
FROM   (SELECT Cast (''<M>'' + Replace('''
           + @Stuff + ''', '','', ''</M><M>'') + ''</M>'' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes (''/M'') AS Split(a) )
                )p
                PIVOT
                (COUNT(colc) FOR colc IN (' + @Stuff+ ')
                )AS pvt'

EXEC Sp_executesql @Sql
```

**OUTPUT :**

*(For Input string 'A1,A2')*

```
+-----+----+----+
|cola | A1 | A2 |
+-----+----+----+
|101  | 1  | 1  |
+-----+----+----+
```

*(For Input string 'A1')*

```
+-----+----+
|cola | A1 |
+-----+----+
|401  | 1  |
+-----+----+
```

Comment: Whoever down-voted please comment why it is not useful. So that i can fix

Comment: Not my DV but an explanation of what the code is doing and why it works would make this a much better answer. :)

Comment: Please retest your script by inserting these records into table: `101 4234 A5`, `201 3434 A1`, `201 3435 A6`. And now pass `@stuff = A1,A2,A5`. Please don't delete previous records keep those and these records too.