# Dynamic pivot table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the following table with the details as shown below in the example.

**Example**:

**Table:** test

```
create table test
(
 cola varchar(10),
 colb varchar(10),
 colc varchar(10)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
insert into test values('111','222','A1');
insert into test values('111','333','A2');
insert into test values('111','344','A3');
insert into test values('111','444','A4');
insert into test values('767','222','A1');
insert into test values('767','333','A2');
insert into test values('767','344','A3');
insert into test values('5443','555','B1');
insert into tft values('8998','222','A1');
insert into tft values('8998','333','A2');    
insert into tft values('8998','353','A8'); 
insert into test values('5443','555','B1');
```

**Note**: Now I want to show only that records in which `cola` belongs to `colc`'s values `A1,A2,A3`.

**Expected Result's**:

**Scenario:1**

**IF** @Stuff = `A1,A2,A3`

Then the result should be:

```
cola   A1  A2  A3
------------------
767    1   1   1
```

**Note**: In the above result the `111` not appeared because of it also belongs to `A4`.

**Scenario:2**

**IF** @Stuff = `A1,A2,A8`

Then the result should be:

```
cola   A1  A2  A8
------------------
8998    1   1   1
```

**Note**: In the above result the `767` not appeared because of it belongs to `A3` not `A8`.

**Scenario:3**

**IF** @Stuff = `A1,A2,A3,A4`

Then the result should be:

```
cola   A1  A2  A3  A4
---------------------
111    1   1   1   1
```

**Note**: In the above result the `111` exactly belongs to `A1,A2,A3,A4`.

**Scenario:4**

**IF** @Stuff = `B1`

Then the result should be:

```
cola   B1  
----------
5443   2
```

**Note**: In the above result the `5443` is appeared two times with the `B1`.

## Attempt:

**Pivot Query**:

```
DECLARE @Stuff varchar(max) = 'A1,A2,A3'
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT cola,' +@Stuff+ '
            from
            (
                select cola,colc
                from test 
            )p
            PIVOT
            (
                COUNT(colc)
                FOR colc IN ('+@Stuff+')
            )AS pvt'

PRINT(@Sql)
EXEC(@Sql)
```

**Getting Result**:

```
cola    A1  A2  A3
-------------------
111     1   1   1
5443    0   0   0
767     1   1   1
8998    1   1   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a different issue with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077468/sql-server-2008-r2-dynamic-query-for-pivot-table-with-where-and-having-clause/27089622?noredirect=1#comment42754477_27089622)?

```
DECLARE @Stuff varchar(max) = 'A1,A2,A3'
        DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)
DECLARE @totalparam varchar(max) = len(@Stuff) - len(replace(@Stuff,',',''))+1
DECLARE @colcList varchar(max) = REPLACE(@Stuff,',',''',''')
        SET @Sql = 'SELECT cola,' +@Stuff+ '
                    FROM
                    (SELECT a.cola, a.colc from test a JOIN (
                        SELECT cola, COUNT(InList) AS InList, COUNT(TOTAL) AS TOTAL FROM (
                               SELECT cola, 
                                     CASE WHEN colc IN ( '''+@colcList+''') THEN
                                         1
                                      END AS InList, 
                                      1 AS TOTAL FROM test
                                group by cola, colc) AS tester group by cola) b  ON a.cola = b.cola
                        WHERE b.TOTAL = '+@totalparam+' AND b.InList = b.TOTAL
                        )p
                PIVOT
                (
                    COUNT(colc)
                    FOR colc IN ('+@Stuff+')
                )AS pvt'
    PRINT(@colcList)
    PRINT(@Sql)
    EXEC(@Sql)
```